# mysql - update value is current value plus new value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-update

I have the following update query.  `shots_limit` needs to be its current value in the database PLUS my new value `$add_shots`.  Is there any way to do this when using bindings?

```
//figure out how many screenshots to add
$add_shots = $_POST['Quantity'] * 500;

$stmt = $db->prepare("
    UPDATE accounts 
    SET orders = :orders,
        shots_limit = :shots_limit
    WHERE account_id = :account_id  
");

//bindings
$binding = array(
    'orders' => $orders_str,
    'shots_limit' => $add_shots + ORIGINAL VALUE
    'account_id' => $result['account_id']
);

$status = $stmt->execute($binding);
```

Comment: That part wasn't code it was used to explain what I want to do there.

Comment: You can try as `shots_limit = :shots_limit+shots_limit` and then just bind `:shots_limit`

Comment: where 'shots_limit' refers to the original value plus my binded value... makes sense.  I know I have done this before in a 'regular' query, but never when using bindings. Going to try this one out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is what you are looking for. Just use current value in update

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("
    UPDATE accounts 
    SET orders = :orders,
        shots_limit = shots_limit + :shots_limit
    WHERE account_id = :account_id  
");

//bindings
$binding = array(
    'orders' => $orders_str,
    'shots_limit' => $add_shots,
    'account_id' => $result['account_id']
);
```